# Best nesting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, nested

I have spent time looking for information on the best algorithm to create a nesting of irregular polygons in 2D using manual and automatic positioning. I need to use such an algorithm in the context of CAD/CAM software. Here are the real possibilities I've found so far:

- **Separating Axis Theorem**: is a fairly quick and simple algorithm to implement, but the drawback I find with it is that it only works with convex polygons. To work with concave polygons, a convex decomposition would need to be done first. This implies an increase in the run-time and the implementation of a new algorithm that decomposes the concave polygon into convex polygons.
- **Nesting by a power function**: calculating the partial derivatives in the X and Y axes, you could get the escape direction you should take a polygon so that there is a collision between the two polygons. This function of energy and I tested and the three major problems that I have encountered are: first obtaining local minima , second nesting when the collision occurs over a piece and finally the execution time is very high.
- Using **no-fit polygon**: use the no-fit polygon to the nesting can be somewhat interesting. I have read several papers on the subject although there are very few online documentation on it. Not sure if it can really be a useful choice. I still have several doubts on the details of this approach.

Any idea which of these algorithms to choose? Or if you know any other options that can be used? I'm a little confused :-) .

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I'd try xposting this at MathOverflow.net

Comment: Pretty cool challenge(+1). Personally I would probably go for a naive and brute force approach: using a vertlett/spring system and use it so solve collisions

Comment: I think this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675123/nesting-maximum-amount-of-shapes-on-a-surface) might be related.

Comment: What you have described here is not nesting algorithms but some way to calculate the overlapping/collision when implementing some nesting algorithm.