Catia nesting application
in CATIA V5 there is no nesting function so I wanted to make a nesting application from c#.
Firstly, I start with opening a product file with a part which is have a limit of my material. I gave it x and y dimensions for limitation like this:
 INFITF.Application catiaApp = (INFITF.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("CATIA.Application");

 Documents catDocuments = catiaApp.Documents;
 PartDocument partDoc = (PartDocument)catDocuments.Add("Part");
 Part part = partDoc.Part;

 Bodies bodies = part.Bodies;
 MECMOD.Body body = bodies.Item("PartBody");
 Sketches sketches = body.Sketches;

 OriginElements originElements = part.OriginElements;
 Reference planeXY = (Reference)originElements.PlaneXY;

 Sketch sketch = sketches.Add(planeXY);

 Factory2D factory2D = sketch.OpenEdition();

 double xValue = Convert.ToDouble(xTextBox.Text);
 double yValue = Convert.ToDouble(yTextBox.Text);

 Point2D point1 = factory2D.CreatePoint(xValue, yValue);
 Point2D point2 = factory2D.CreatePoint(0, yValue);
 Point2D point3 = factory2D.CreatePoint(xValue, 0);
 Point2D point4 = factory2D.CreatePoint(0, 0);

 Line2D line1 = factory2D.CreateLine(0, yValue, xValue, yValue);
 line1.StartPoint = point2;
 line1.EndPoint = point1;

 Line2D line2 = factory2D.CreateLine(xValue, yValue, xValue, 0);
 line2.StartPoint = point1;
 line2.EndPoint = point3;

 Line2D line3 = factory2D.CreateLine(xValue, 0, 0, 0);
 line3.StartPoint = point3;
 line3.EndPoint = point4;

 Line2D line4 = factory2D.CreateLine(0, 0, 0, yValue);
 line4.StartPoint = point4;
 line4.EndPoint = point2;

 sketch.CloseEdition();
 part.Update();

Then I created a list for my all catpart what I needed for nesting and choose surface for nesting area:
 OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
 dialog.Filter = "CATIA Part Files (*.CATPart)|*.CATPart";
 dialog.Multiselect = true; 
 if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
     foreach (string file in dialog.FileNames) // Seçilen tüm dosyalar
     {
         string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file); // Yalnızca dosya adını alır
         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(fileName, 1); // İkinci sütuna otomatik olarak "1" yazdırılır

         // CATIA'da dosyayı aç
         try
         {
             catiaApp.Documents.Open(file); // Her dosyayı CATIA'da aç
             PartDocument partDocument = (PartDocument)catiaApp.ActiveDocument;
             Part part = partDocument.Part;

             Selection selection = partDocument.Selection;
             object[] filter = { "Face" };
             string status = selection.SelectElement2(filter, "", false);

             if (status == "Normal")
             {
                 Reference selectedFace = (Reference)selection.Item(1).Reference;

                 HybridShapeFactory hybridShapeFactory = (HybridShapeFactory)part.HybridShapeFactory;

                 HybridShapeInverse hybridShapeInverse = hybridShapeFactory.AddNewInverse(selectedFace, -1);

                 HybridBodies hybridBodies = part.HybridBodies;
                 HybridBody hybridBody = hybridBodies.Item("Geometrical Set.1");

                 hybridBody.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeInverse);
                 part.InWorkObject = hybridShapeInverse;
                 part.Update();

                 Reference reference2 = part.CreateReferenceFromObject(hybridShapeInverse);
                 HybridShapeBoundary hybridShapeBoundary = hybridShapeFactory.AddNewBoundaryOfSurface(reference2);

                 hybridBody.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapeBoundary);
                 part.InWorkObject = hybridShapeBoundary;
                 part.Update();
             }
             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Bir yüz seçilmedi. İşlem iptal edildi.");
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show($"Dosya açılamadı: {fileName}\nHata: {ex.Message}");
         }
     }
 }

Now I will open a product, add my x y rectangle limiter part then I start to paste my nesting parts...
But there is something off. How can I make iterations of nesting in catia?
I have idea about placing parts from translation, rotation. And about limitation I can use constraint to my limit rectangle and between parts with offset which I entered to textbox.
Where should I start for this calculation of nesting part?
My app

Can you please detail your question about iteration/nesting? Are you asking for nesting algorithm? (maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675123/nesting-maximum-amount-of-shapes-on-a-surface)

@Shrotter hello again, I want to make a nesting by surface boundry from every part in product for example 5 mm blanks between surfaces like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOy-y2-HLss
Also I made my version I adding part into product but didn't figure it out how to give them 5 mm blanks from parts maybe offset contraction. from limits to boundies max values

@Shrotter I upload mines check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QKfhDFSbmg

I wouldn't use constrains. I would position the parts via coordinates (calculated via a nesting algorithm?) To check the distance between parts you could use a measurement.

@Shrotter I'm working with wrl data I got boundry and save it to wrl. After that I got point and line values to table. Now trying to get simple nesting.
